# Confirmation Dialog is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have never worked in jquery before. This is my first time. I need it for some confirmation dialog. I have write this to test it first before applying in my project. I have written this code. I want dialog box only if specified radio button is selected.

Main Problem: Show Confirmation Dialog if Specified Option in radio button is selected.

Jquery code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.checkLeave = function() {
        return this.each(function(){

            if($("input[name='second']").is(':checked')) {
                alert("Second Radio Button is CLicked");
                $.confirm({
                    text: "Are you sure to submit the form",
                        title: "Confirmation required",
                        confirm: function(button) {
                          $("form").submit();
                        },
                        cancel: function(button) {
                        // nothing to do
                        },
                        confirmButton: "Yes",
                        cancelButton: "No",
                        post: true,
                        confirmButtonClass: "btn-default",
                        cancelButtonClass: "btn-danger",
                        dialogClass: "modal-dialog modal-lg" 
                });     
            }
            });
    };

})( jQuery );
```

and HTML is:

```
 <form action="dialogJquery.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="radio" id="first">
    <input type="radio" name="second" checked="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" name="confirm"
      onclick="$(this).checkLeave();"></button>
 </form>
```

The above code shows the alert defined before dialog. but after that dialog is not shown. This is from where i am using [Jquery Dialog Plugin](https://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/). But through debugging when debugger reaches $.confirm and i click on step over then dialog is shown but when i resume script it again disappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that the form is being submitted because your code is doing nothing to stop it from being submitted.  Accordingly, the dialog is being shown only for the duration of time it takes for the browser to submit the form and go to the specified page (dialogJquery.html).

Once someone who is a better programmer looks at this, they can likely come up with a better solution, but following is what I came up with that seems to work.  I have added some IDs to elements and such--you should be able to follow that without further explanation.  One thing I found is that if any of the elements has a name or ID of "submit" then the .submit() function will not work on the form.

In general, I handle the submit event for the form and preventDefault so that it doesn't submit.  The confirm button sets submitConfirm to true and submits the form.

***HTML***

```
  <form id="myForm" action="dialogJquery.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="radio" id="first">
    <input type="radio" name="second" checked>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" name="confirm">
  </form>
```

***Javascript***

```
(function($) {
  var submitConfirm = false;

  $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    if (!submitConfirm) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($("input[name='second']").is(':checked')) {
        $.confirm({
          text: "Are you sure to submit the form",
          title: "Confirmation required",
          confirm: function(button) {
            submitConfirm = true;
            $("#myForm").submit();
          },
          cancel: function(button) {
            // nothing to do
          },
          confirmButton: "Yes",
          cancelButton: "No",
          post: true,
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-default",
          cancelButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          dialogClass: "modal-dialog modal-lg"
        });
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Now the debugger do not even comes to if condition.

Comment: It worked for me with that exact HTML and script.  Did you change your HTML to what I provided?

Comment: yeah i have changed everything what you have written.

Comment: That's interesting.  I did it on jsfiddle in Chrome.  I would recommend that you create a jsfiddle for it and share it.

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhan Here is a JSFiddle with it working: https://jsfiddle.net/tonyhinkle/ejpjzees/  The only thing added in the fiddle is the jquery.confirm code that is at the top of the javascript code pane, which has to be loaded before your code, which is at the bottom of the pane.

Comment: Thanks A lot . I have just created new file and paste these over there and it started working. Thank you